# Resources To Learn How To Use Chessbase

Tags: learning, beginner, database, chessbase, coach

Chessbase comes up practically everywhere as key software to use for chess improvement, accessing and playing through games, researching etc. As an adult improver (1900 Chess.com), beginner chess coach and budding chess content creator, I identified it was probably a good idea to get Chessbase.

Having made the bold decision to buy the Chessbase 17 and Fritz 18 bundle, I’ve found it is incredibly hard to learn to use and haven’t come across a quick way to get to fully appreciate its optimal usage for my development and work. As a result I’m under utilising it and am yet to reap a return on my investment.

Part of the problem is that I’m hopeless with user manuals, my approach has always been to just dive in and figure it all out. In Chessbase, I’ve however met my match. Admittedly I have a technical knowledge gap, which I’m slowly filling with regards to what Chessbase really is and all it’s associated databases, engines, file formats etc. It’s a whole new world for me.

I see some user frustration with Chessbase in online comments. There seems to be a common theme that it’s difficult to learn and use. I take some solace in knowing that I am not alone. I’m however determined to learn and to benefit from Chessbase by using it as an effective tool.

Please help by pointing me to resources I can access to help me learn all about Chessbase in an efficient and structured way. With your help, I will not be defeated .

Answer (score 2):

The best comprehensive guide for Chessbase that I have found is the two books of Jon Edwards. In 2014 Russel Enterprises published his 350 page "*ChessBase Complete*" covering Chessbase up to version 12 and in 2019 this was followed up by a slim 90 page booklet by the same author bringing the main work up to date for versions 13, 14 and 15, "*ChessBase Complete, 2019 Supplement covering ChessBase 13, 14 &15*".

Of course Chessbase has continued to extend and improve. So, I would also recommend the YouTube video on the ChessBase India channel by IM Sagar Shah, [All the ChessBase 17 new features explained in depth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf5NC-dmfQ8&ab_channel=ChessBaseIndia), from December 2022.